# Adobe Flash CS6. How to rotate button and save his label?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, adobe, label

I have problem in Adobe flash professional CS6, after I rotate the button label hidding. What can be problem? I can't find isue.

Here is before rotating

[image: normal]

And here is after rotating, without label.

[image: bad]

Button's instance name "ZaistiPradzia". In AS3 Button's format looks like:

```
ZaistiPradzia.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, play);



            var button2:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            button2.font = "Arial";
            button2.size = 36;
            button2.bold = true;
            button2.color = 0xf15b25;

ZaistiPradzia.setStyle("textFormat", button2);
```

Have you ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For see rotated labels you should embed font to you project. It is multistep proccess so all information you need, you could find [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/button_component_as3.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_5)